# How to check if a child-object is populated

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

How can i check if a child-object of a linq-object is populated or not? Example code below.

My model have two methods, one joins data, and the other does not:

```
public static Member GetMemberWithPhoto(Guid memberId)
{
    using (DataContext db = new DataContext())
    {
        DataLoadOptions dataLoadOptions = new DataLoadOptions();
        dataLoadOptions.LoadWith<Member>(x => x.UserPhoto);
        db.LoadOptions = dataLoadOptions;

        var query = from x in db.Members
                    where x.MemberId == memberId
                    select x;

        return query.FirstOrDefault();
    }
}

public static Member GetMember(Guid memberId)
{
    using (DataContext db = new DataContext())
    {
        var query = from x in db.Members
                    where x.MemberId == memberId
                    select x;

        return query.FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Then my control have the following code:

```
Member member1 = Member.GetMemberWithPhoto(memberId);
Member member2 = Member.GetMember(memberId);

Debug.WriteLine(member1.UserPhoto.ToString());
Debug.WriteLine(member2.UserPhoto.ToString());
```

The last line will generate a "Cannot access a disposed object" exception. I know that i can get rid of that  exception just by not disposing the datacontext, but then the last line will generate a new query to the database, and i don't want that.

What i would like is something like:

```
Debug.WriteLine((member1.UserPhoto.IsPopulated()) ? member1.UserPhoto.ToString() : "none");
Debug.WriteLine((member2.UserPhoto.IsPopulated()) ? member2.UserPhoto.ToString() : "none");
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the Settings property defined as an EntitySet? If so, then you should be able to inspect the HasLoadedOrAssignedValues property:

```
Debug.WriteLine(member1.Settings.HasLoadedOrAssignedValues ? member2.Settings.Count : -1);
```

Comment: You are of course correct. I just realized however that the code i have problem with is not an entityset, but a one-to-one relation in the database. I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: What does the property accessor look like for the one-to-one? Does it access a field of type EntityRef<T>? If so, you could create another property IsUserPhotoPopulated (perhaps on a partial class), that does a check on the field as follows _userPhoto.HasLoadedOrAssignedValue. Or, modify the logic of the getter to perform this check itself, although it will get overwritten when you regenerate your entity model (if it was auto-generated).

Comment: Both the Member and UserPhoto objects are autogenerared from corresponding tables via a dbml-file in visual studio, and as far as i can tell there are no EntityRef<T>'s anywhere. I could create new properties in partial classes, but i don't know if that will help. I could modify the logic of the queries as well, but it's a big project with lot's of old code, some joins the data and some does not, so i'd prefer if another method exists.

Comment: What does the property acessor look like for UserPhoto if you view it in designer.cs? It should be accessing a field of EntityRef<T>, unless your Linq to SQL generates code differently from mine.

Comment: That did it, thanx! I created a new property in the partial class for Member called HasUserPhoto with "return this._UserPhoto.HasLoadedOrAssignedValue;".